# Optional but mutually exclusive switches in a function

Tags: powershell

I want to write a function in a custom powershell module that can defines some switches.

The function should be call aither with no switch at all, or with one switch. Multiple switches are not allowed.

Ex:

```
Get-Foo -Value "text"                          # Should return "text"
Get-Foo -Value "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z" -AsDate  # Should return the value as date
Get-Foo -Value "42" -AsInteger                 # Should return 42 as integer
Get-Foo -Value "xxx" -AsDate -AsInteger        # Should fail
```

In order to support these cases, I'm playing with parameter sets :

```
function Get-Foo{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Value,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AsDate')]
        [Switch]$AsDate,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AsInteger')]
        [Switch]$AsInteger

    )

    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        "AsDate" {
            [datetime]::Parse($Value)
        }
        "AsInteger" {
            [int]::Parse($Value)
        }
        "__AllParameterSets" { 
            $Value
        }
    }
}
```

However, this does not works as expected. Passing one of the two switches works. Passing the two switches fails (but it's intended).

PAssing no switch at all fails, because it can't resolve the parameter set.

How to fix this ?

Comment: Does this look like an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767219/mutually-exclusive-powershell-parameters

Comment: @RohinSidharth, not really. The answer you suggest only specify how to use parameter sets, not how to solve the "no switch" case.thx anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give the function a `DefaultParameterSetName`, and change the last switch test to be `Default`, things should work:

```
function Get-Foo {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'None')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Value,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AsDate')]
        [Switch]$AsDate,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AsInteger')]
        [Switch]$AsInteger

    )

    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        "AsDate" {
            [datetime]::Parse($Value)
        }
        "AsInteger" {
            [int]::Parse($Value)
        }
        default { 
            $Value
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

> ```
> Get-Foo -Value "text"                          # Returns "text"
> Get-Foo -Value "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z" -AsDate  # Returns the value as date (if Parse() is possible)
> Get-Foo -Value "42" -AsInteger                 # Returns 42 as integer (if Parse() is possible)
> Get-Foo -Value "xxx" -AsDate -AsInteger        # Fails
> ```

<sup>Note: for more complex Switch() comparisons, consider the `break` statement to stop the switch from comparing after a match. See [about_Switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-6)</sup>

Comment: It's exactly what I need ! Thanks